# Send variable from function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code

```
 socket.on('user joined',function(data){
       var ume = data.username;
        $('#userlist').append("<li id='"+ume+"'><a href='#' onclick='prePrivate("+ume+"); return false;'>"+ume+"</a></li>");
        console.log(ume);
 });
```

and prePrivate method

```
  function prePrivate(userprivate){
        privateuser = userprivate;
        console.log(privateuser);
  }
```

When i click `li` element, console print

```
<li id="sample_data">
```

but not print sample_data.
I do not understand, how to get variable. Sorry my english not good

Comment: what variable are you looking for?

Comment: i want get value of variable "ume" but code print <li id="sample_data">

Comment: example: ume = "hoang" , i want console print hoang, but console print <li id="hoang">

Comment: you need to add quotes around `ume` in the string where you call prePrivate onclick: `...onclick='prePrivate(\""+ume+"\"); ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes around ume in the prePrivate call in the string that you are building: `...onclick='prePrivate(\""+ume+"\");...`

Without them you are calling `prePrivate(sample_data)` and `sample_data` happens to be the DOM `li` element you just id'ed with that same name instead of a string. Why? See [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)